# Trying to get specific string from different class after json deserialize

Tags: c#, json, class

I'm very new in C# and what I'm trying to do is build a web service when user can put latitude and longitude and get the 'google type' back.
I want to obtain the 'type[]' from 'address_component'.
How will I do that?

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

using System.Web.Extensions;
// using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://idanmoshe.com/", Description = "Idans' web services")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]


public class NetroadsWebServices : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public NetroadsWebServices()
    {
        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }


    [WebMethod (Description = "Get google type by coordinate (road, street etc.)")]
    public string getGoogleType(float latitude, float longitude)
    {
        string completeUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&sensor=true";
        var jsonString = new WebClient().DownloadString(completeUrl);
        Console.WriteLine ("Complete URL: "+completeUrl);

        JavaScriptSerializer jsonParse = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        GoogleGeoCodeResponse getTypes = jsonParse.Deserialize<GoogleGeoCodeResponse>(jsonString);


        return jsonString;
    }
}

public class GoogleGeoCodeResponse
{

    public string status { get; set; }
    public results[] results { get; set; }

}

public class results
{
    public string formatted_address { get; set; }
    public geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public string[] types { get; set; }
    public address_component[] address_components { get; set; }
}

public class geometry
{
    public string location_type { get; set; }
    public location location { get; set; }
}

public class location
{
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string lng { get; set; }
}

public class address_component
{
    public string long_name { get; set; }
    public string short_name { get; set; }
    public string[] types { get; set; }
}
```

Example for output string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://idanmoshe.com/">{ "results" : [ { "address_components" : [ { "long_name" : "Al Ismaileya - Port Saeed", "short_name" : "Al Ismaileya - Port Saeed", "types" : [ "route" ] }, { "long_name" : "Qesm Awal Al Ganoub", "short_name" : "Qesm Awal Al Ganoub", "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ] }, { "long_name" : "Port Said", "short_name" : "Port Said", "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ] }, { "long_name" : "Egypt", "short_name" : "EG", "types" : [ "country", "political" ] } ], "formatted_address" : "Al Ismaileya - Port Saeed, Qesm Awal Al Ganoub, Port Said, Egypt", "geometry" : { "bounds" : { "northeast" : { "lat" : 31.10762660, "lng" : 32.20366510 }, "southwest" : { "lat" : 31.01789770, "lng" : 32.20137170 } }, "location" : { "lat" : 31.06282650, "lng" : 32.20248240 }, "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE", "viewport" : { "northeast" : { "lat" : 31.10762660, "lng" : 32.20386738029149 }, "southwest" : { "lat" : 31.01789770, "lng" : 32.20116941970849 } } }, "types" : [ "route" ] }, { "address_components" : [ { "long_name" : "Qesm Awal Al Ganoub", "short_name" : "Qesm Awal Al Ganoub", "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ] }, { "long_name" : "Port Said", "short_name" : "Port Said", "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ] }, { "long_name" : "Egypt", "short_name" : "EG", "types" : [ "country", "political" ] } ], "formatted_address" : "Qesm Awal Al Ganoub, Port Said, Egypt", "geometry" : { "bounds" : { "northeast" : { "lat" : 31.34955880, "lng" : 32.28690060 }, "southwest" : { "lat" : 31.01694570, "lng" : 32.05233060 } }, "location" : { "lat" : 31.12950940, "lng" : 32.22000650 }, "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE", "viewport" : { "northeast" : { "lat" : 31.34955880, "lng" : 32.28690060 }, "southwest" : { "lat" : 31.01694570, "lng" : 32.05233060 } } }, "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ] }, { "address_components" : [ { "long_name" : "Port Said", "short_name" : "Port Said", "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ] }, { "long_name" : "Egypt", "short_name" : "EG", "types" : [ "country", "political" ] } ], "formatted_address" : "Port Said, Egypt", "geometry" : { "bounds" : { "northeast" : { "lat" : 31.36418070, "lng" : 32.5629240 }, "southwest" : { "lat" : 30.88772540, "lng" : 32.05233060 } }, "location" : { "lat" : 31.07586060, "lng" : 32.26538870 }, "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE", "viewport" : { "northeast" : { "lat" : 31.36418070, "lng" : 32.5629240 }, "southwest" : { "lat" : 30.88772540, "lng" : 32.05233060 } } }, "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ] }, { "address_components" : [ { "long_name" : "Egypt", "short_name" : "EG", "types" : [ "country", "political" ] } ], "formatted_address" : "Egypt", "geometry" : { "bounds" : { "northeast" : { "lat" : 31.6715350, "lng" : 36.89454460 }, "southwest" : { "lat" : 21.99999990, "lng" : 24.69677480 } }, "location" : { "lat" : 26.8205530, "lng" : 30.8024980 }, "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE", "viewport" : { "northeast" : { "lat" : 31.6715350, "lng" : 36.89454460 }, "southwest" : { "lat" : 21.99999990, "lng" : 24.69677480 } } }, "types" : [ "country", "political" ] } ], "status" : "OK" } </string>
```

Comment: can you post an example string?

Comment: I've added an example for output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(var result in getTypes.results)
{
   foreach(var address_component in result.address_components)
   {
        var types = address_component.types;
   }
}
```

Note: `types` will be the array of strings. 
So, to extract the values you can either use an explicit index like: `types[0]` or 
iterate through them:

```
foreach(var type in types)
{
   // type is the string 
   Console.WriteLine(type);
}
```

Comment: OK, how can I cast the 'var' to 'string' as I cannot 'return' var (Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized)?

Comment: @IdanMoshe you can't return var, because var represents string[]. If you want a single string to return see my update

Comment: Yes, but I still don't know how to assign the 'var' to 'string'.

Comment: in which part? the var "is" a string, by using "var" is implicitly typed. you can do: string type = types[0]; It depends on which type you want to return in the array.

Comment: OK, it works as you wrote 'string type = types[0];'. Many thanks man!